# Selecting all when deleting emails on iOS 7?

Tags: ios, mobile-mail

I'm working on a users phone and they're complaining about spam emails that they get on their AOL account. Many of the emails have the same titles, and thus should be easy to delete en-masse.

I got as far as searching for the title of the email, clicking search, and then clicking edit, which brings up a list of checkmarks to the left from which you can select the emails to be deleted.  However, you can't check all of them without checking off through ever single stink'n one.

Is there a way I can bulk delete hundreds or more emails on AOL from just the one sender using iOS?

Comment: Is the account entry setup to access the email servers with IMAP or POP?

Comment: @glenschler It uses Microsoft Office 365 / Exchange 365.

Comment: So it is the Office 365 email client, not the native iphone email client?

Comment: Oh sorry; the user has two email accounts on her iPhone.  One connects to our company Office 365 / Exchange 365 account; and the other account connects to AOL.